# Where are the pictures of my JSF page?

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, spring-security

I have a navigation-rule like this in my JSF 2 application:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{myBean.goToMyHome1}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>myHome1.xhtml</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/myhome1/myHome1.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

When I put an `h:commandLink` in `myHome2.xhtml` within directory `myhome2` that satisfy this rule, the page `myHome1.xhtml` will display but there are no images on the page. Where they go?
Behind the application is Springsecurity 3 with this config:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/myhome1/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE1','ROLE2')" />
```

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/myhome2/**" access="hasRole('ROLE2')" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This look like as if your picture URLs are relative to the current URL path. E.g.

```xml
<img src="images/picture.png" />
```

When you open the page by

> http://example.com/contextname/myHome1.xhtml

then the image URL will effectively point to

> http://example.com/contextname/images/picture.png

But when you open the page by

> http://example.com/contextname/myhome/myHome1.xhtml

then the image URL will effectively point to

> http://example.com/contextname/myhome/images/picture.png

You need to fix it accordingly. There are several ways. Use a domain-relative path

```xml
<img src="/contextname/images/picture.png" />
```

Or prepend the context name dynamically

```xml
<img src="#{request.contextPath}/images/picture.png" />
```

Or just use `<h:graphicImage>` which will do that automatically

```xml
<h:graphicImage value="/images/picture.png" />
```